# Struts - getting NPE when passing parameters to bean property

Tags: struts, properties, jstl, nullpointerexception

I have a bean property in my form as follows (rates is a HashMap from FleetRateTypeCO to FleetRate[]):

```
public FleetRate[] getRatesByType(int typeID) {
    return this.rates.get(FleetRateTypeCO.getByID(typeID));
}
```

Then in my jsp I want to do the following:

```
<c:when test="${not empty DedicatedFleetContractAdminForm.ratesByType[1]}">
  ...
</c:when>
```

But I get a null pointer exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:259)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:209)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:60)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:97)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:29)
```

But what really confuses me is that if I try the following, it works fine:

```
<logic:iterate property="ratesByType[1]" name="DedicatedFleetContractAdminForm" id="overheadRates">
    ...
</logic:iterate>
```

Why would they work differently? Any help is appreciated - thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In one you are using the struts tags, and in the other EL.

Try using the struts  tag